# Замена части элемента ячейки в датафрейм Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, поиск, замена

Помогите, пожалуйста, знающие люди.
Не пойму каким оператором воспользоваться

Имеется датафрейм

```
Полоса  Позиция
1       24-1
1       24-2
1       24-2
2       1-1
2       1-1
2       1-2
2       1-3
2       1-4
3       2-1
3       2-2
3       2-2
3       2-3
```

Как можно в столбце Позиция первое число заменить на число из столбца Полоса не меняя второе число

Надо в итоге получить:

```
Полоса  Позиция
1       1-1
1       1-2
1       1-2
2       2-1
2       2-1
2       2-2
2       2-3
2       2-4
3       3-1
3       3-2
3       3-2
3       3-3
```

И еще похожий вопрос - как с помощью регулярного выражения добавить символ в текст ячейки.
Например, найти все ФАМИЛИИ (написаны заглавными буквами) в текстовой ячейке с разным другим текстом и затем добавить о всем фамилиям во всех ячейках знак "?".
Тут вероятно применить нужно поиск по шаблону ко всем ячейкам столбца?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

что касается первого вопроса, то можно попробовать что-то вроде этого:

```
df['Позиция'] = df['Полоса'].astype('str').str.cat(df['Позиция'].str.extract('(-\d+)'))
'''
    Полоса Позиция
0        1     1-1
1        1     1-2
2        1     1-2
3        2     2-1
4        2     2-1
5        2     2-2
6        2     2-3
7        2     2-4
8        3     3-1
9        3     3-2
10       3     3-2
11       3     3-3
```

а что касается второго вопроса, то приведите воспроизводимый фрагмент данныx и пример необходимого результата, ну и еще правила требуют показать свои попытки решения.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает!

Answer (score 3):

можно так попробовать

```
df["Позиция"] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub('\d{2}', str(x['Полоса']), x['Позиция']), axis=1)

>>> df
    Полоса     Позиция
0        1      1-1
1        1      1-2
2        1      1-2
3        2      1-1
4        2      1-1
5        2      1-2
6        2      1-3
7        2      1-4
8        3      2-1
9        3      2-2
10       3      2-2
11       3      2-3
```

чтобы к каждой фамилии в тексте добавить знак вопроса, можно сделать так
(допустим столбец называется *text*)

```
df["text"] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\b([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+)\b', r'\1?', x['text']),
                                           axis=1)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Правда ваши примеры не хотят работать.  По второму шаблону выдает: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object. В чем может быть ошибка? Искал по цифровым столбцам и шаблонам. Та же самая ошибка. Не могу найти ошибку в синтаксисе.

Comment: потому что он работает со строками, с int-овыми столбцами работать не будет, перед этим нужно перевести в строку. а с первым что не так?

Comment: Почему-то тоже не хочет менять, хотя ошибки не выдает. А меняет несколько строк, но не все

Comment: Все разобрался теперь, спасибо за помощь

Comment: Все равно не могу понять, как менять ячейки. Помогите, пожалуйста.

>>> df
    Полоса     Позиция
0        1      1-1
1                1-2
2                1-2
3        2      1-1
4        2      1-1
5        2      1-2
6        2      1-3
7        2      1-4
8                2-1
9        3      2-2
10       3      2-2
11       3      2-3

Comment: немного непонятные данные) скиньте ссылкой на файл)